# Rviz cannot find resource pack/ cannot load model

Tags: rviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello
I am trying to visualize EvARobot on RViz but when I run RViz I get this and I can only see two parts of robot. How can I fix this?
NOTE: evarobot_description and all other files exist.

```
metobom@metobom-TULPAR-T5-V17-1:~$ rosrun rviz rviz
[ INFO] [1549745352.700308037]: rviz version 1.12.16
[ INFO] [1549745352.700362956]: compiled against Qt version 5.5.1
[ INFO] [1549745352.700376228]: compiled against OGRE version 1.9.0 (Ghadamon)
[ INFO] [1549745352.861618679]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[ INFO] [1549745352.861736050]: OpenGl version: 3 (GLSL 1.3).
[rospack] Error: package 'evarobot_description' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1549745352.990890627]: Error retrieving file [package://evarobot_description/meshes/base.stl]: Package [evarobot_description] does not exist
[ WARN] [1549745352.991040897]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/base.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1549745352.991178442]: Could not load model 'package://evarobot_description/meshes/base.stl' for link 'base_link': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/base.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ WARN] [1549745352.991264554]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/base.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1549745352.991336207]: Could not load model 'package://evarobot_description/meshes/base.stl' for link 'base_link': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/base.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[rospack] Error: package 'evarobot_description' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1549745353.013034291, 94.949000000]: Error retrieving file [package://evarobot_description/meshes/base_orange.stl]: Package [evarobot_description] does not exist
[ WARN] [1549745353.013137282, 94.949000000]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/base_orange.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1549745353.013211398, 94.949000000]: Could not load model 'package://evarobot_description/meshes/base_orange.stl' for link 'basecolor_link': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/base_orange.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ WARN] [1549745353.013272989, 94.949000000]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/base_orange.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1549745353.013344071, 94.949000000]: Could not load model 'package://evarobot_description/meshes/base_orange.stl' for link 'basecolor_link': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/base_orange.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[rospack] Error: package 'evarobot_description' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1549745353.033654420, 94.964000000]: Could not load resource [package://evarobot_description/meshes/xtion_pro_camera.dae]: Unable to open file "package://evarobot_description/meshes/xtion_pro_camera.dae".
[ WARN] [1549745353.033772348, 94.964000000]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/xtion_pro_camera.dae in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1549745353.033832915, 94.964000000]: Could not load model 'package://evarobot_description/meshes/xtion_pro_camera.dae' for link 'camera_link': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/xtion_pro_camera.dae in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ WARN] [1549745353.033888545, 94.964000000]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/xtion_pro_camera.dae in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1549745353.033936353, 94.964000000]: Could not load model 'package://evarobot_description/meshes/xtion_pro_camera.dae' for link 'camera_link': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/xtion_pro_camera.dae in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[rospack] Error: package 'evarobot_description' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1549745353.053691825, 94.978000000]: Error retrieving file [package://evarobot_description/meshes/caster_base.stl]: Package [evarobot_description] does not exist
[ WARN] [1549745353.053779106, 94.978000000]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/caster_base.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1549745353.053836019, 94.978000000]: Could not load model 'package://evarobot_description/meshes/caster_base.stl' for link 'front_caster_base_link': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/caster_base.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ WARN] [1549745353.053893038, 94.978000000]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/caster_base.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1549745353.053937197, 94.978000000]: Could not load model 'package://evarobot_description/meshes/caster_base.stl' for link 'front_caster_base_link': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/caster_base.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[rospack] Error: package 'evarobot_description' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1549745353.073883213, 94.992000000]: Error retrieving file [package://evarobot_description/meshes/caster_rot.stl]: Package [evarobot_description] does not exist
[ WARN] [1549745353.073974137, 94.992000000]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/caster_rot.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1549745353.074030648, 94.992000000]: Could not load model 'package://evarobot_description/meshes/caster_rot.stl' for link 'front_caster_rotate_link': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/caster_rot.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ WARN] [1549745353.074081443, 94.992000000]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/caster_rot.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1549745353.074127367, 94.992000000]: Could not load model 'package://evarobot_description/meshes/caster_rot.stl' for link 'front_caster_rotate_link': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/caster_rot.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[rospack] Error: package 'evarobot_description' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1549745353.094727776, 95.001000000]: Error retrieving file [package://evarobot_description/meshes/rim.stl]: Package [evarobot_description] does not exist
[ WARN] [1549745353.094872175, 95.001000000]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/rim.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1549745353.094947388, 95.001000000]: Could not load model 'package://evarobot_description/meshes/rim.stl' for link 'left_wheel_link': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/rim.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ WARN] [1549745353.095012527, 95.001000000]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/rim.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1549745353.095069549, 95.001000000]: Could not load model 'package://evarobot_description/meshes/rim.stl' for link 'left_wheel_link': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/rim.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[rospack] Error: package 'evarobot_description' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1549745353.114810138, 95.017000000]: Error retrieving file [package://evarobot_description/meshes/tire.stl]: Package [evarobot_description] does not exist
[ WARN] [1549745353.114981737, 95.017000000]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/tire.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1549745353.115066693, 95.017000000]: Could not load model 'package://evarobot_description/meshes/tire.stl' for link 'left_wheeltire_link': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/tire.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ WARN] [1549745353.115144659, 95.017000000]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/tire.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1549745353.115206929, 95.017000000]: Could not load model 'package://evarobot_description/meshes/tire.stl' for link 'left_wheeltire_link': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/tire.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[rospack] Error: package 'evarobot_description' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1549745353.135323109, 95.033000000]: Error retrieving file [package://evarobot_description/meshes/rplidar.stl]: Package [evarobot_description] does not exist
[ WARN] [1549745353.135433924, 95.033000000]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/rplidar.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1549745353.135505087, 95.033000000]: Could not load model 'package://evarobot_description/meshes/rplidar.stl' for link 'lidar_link': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/rplidar.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ WARN] [1549745353.135576767, 95.033000000]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/rplidar.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1549745353.135636525, 95.033000000]: Could not load model 'package://evarobot_description/meshes/rplidar.stl' for link 'lidar_link': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/rplidar.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[rospack] Error: package 'evarobot_description' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1549745353.155818149, 95.049000000]: Error retrieving file [package://evarobot_description/meshes/asus_base.stl]: Package [evarobot_description] does not exist
[ WARN] [1549745353.155932851, 95.049000000]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/asus_base.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1549745353.156024843, 95.049000000]: Could not load model 'package://evarobot_description/meshes/asus_base.stl' for link 'mount_asus_xtion_pro_link': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/asus_base.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ WARN] [1549745353.156097750, 95.049000000]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/asus_base.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1549745353.156154086, 95.049000000]: Could not load model 'package://evarobot_description/meshes/asus_base.stl' for link 'mount_asus_xtion_pro_link': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/asus_base.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ WARN] [1549745353.156472605, 95.050000000]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/caster_base.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1549745353.156543799, 95.050000000]: Could not load model 'package://evarobot_description/meshes/caster_base.stl' for link 'rear_caster_base_link': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/caster_base.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ WARN] [1549745353.156597273, 95.050000000]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/caster_base.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1549745353.156650710, 95.050000000]: Could not load model 'package://evarobot_description/meshes/caster_base.stl' for link 'rear_caster_base_link': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/caster_base.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ WARN] [1549745353.156836321, 95.050000000]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/caster_rot.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1549745353.156903261, 95.050000000]: Could not load model 'package://evarobot_description/meshes/caster_rot.stl' for link 'rear_caster_rotate_link': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/caster_rot.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ WARN] [1549745353.156958385, 95.050000000]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/caster_rot.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1549745353.157012214, 95.050000000]: Could not load model 'package://evarobot_description/meshes/caster_rot.stl' for link 'rear_caster_rotate_link': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/caster_rot.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ WARN] [1549745353.157346026, 95.050000000]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/rim.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1549745353.157426180, 95.050000000]: Could not load model 'package://evarobot_description/meshes/rim.stl' for link 'right_wheel_link': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/rim.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ WARN] [1549745353.157489227, 95.050000000]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/rim.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1549745353.157543220, 95.050000000]: Could not load model 'package://evarobot_description/meshes/rim.stl' for link 'right_wheel_link': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/rim.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ WARN] [1549745353.157744702, 95.050000000]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/tire.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1549745353.157810991, 95.051000000]: Could not load model 'package://evarobot_description/meshes/tire.stl' for link 'right_wheeltire_link': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/tire.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ WARN] [1549745353.157868022, 95.051000000]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/tire.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1549745353.157922439, 95.051000000]: Could not load model 'package://evarobot_description/meshes/tire.stl' for link 'right_wheeltire_link': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://evarobot_description/meshes/tire.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/315188/rviz-cannot-find-resource-pack/-cannot-load-model/) by [metobom](https://answers.ros.org/users/39588/metobom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2019-02-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like `evarobot_description` is not in your workspace.

You need to source (as in `source setup.bash`) the workspace containing this package in the terminal running RViz for Rviz to be able to find it.

The command `rospack find evarobot_description` will tell you if the package is known on your system.

---

Originally posted by [lelongg](https://answers.ros.org/users/33223/lelongg/) with karma: 50 on 2019-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [metobom](https://answers.ros.org/users/39588/metobom/) on 2019-02-09**:
Thanks a lot it worked. That was quick :).